# Is it safe to call printk inside spin_lock_irqsave?

Tags: linux, kernel, sleep, irq, printk

I've written a code something like this:

It is in non-interrupt context:

```
spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);
printk("some message blah...\n");
spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
```

I am running this code and "looks" safe because I don't see any crashes.
But, I'm not sure this is really a safe code or not. Because that may trigger a system crash with 1/100000 probability.

Additionally, I would like to know if calling "sleep" function inside spin_lock_irqsave is safe (in not-interrupt context).

Comment: Does anything else acquire `lock`?

Comment: Yes, could be. And, I would like to put event-wait routine in-between spin_lock_irq...

Answer (score 4):

Kernel code should not sleep while holding a spin lock. In [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf), the "Spinlocks and Atomic Context" section in Chapter 5 states:

```
Therefore, the core rule that applies to spinlocks is that any code must,
while holding a spinlock, be atomic. It cannot sleep; in fact, it cannot
relinquish the processor for any reason except to service interrupts (and
sometimes not even then).
```

As for `printk`, I believe it is safe to call within a critical section. The comments in the [source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/printk/printk.c#L1814) even mention:

```
This is printk(). It can be called from any context. We want it to work.
```

Comment: Actually, it is not a driver code. The context is a kernel thread, not a interrupt context. But, for some reason, I would like to disable interrupt with holding the spin-lock.

Comment: Both drivers and "normal" kernel threads follow roughly the same rules, but I updated the answer to clarify.